# How can I delete iOS crash reporter logs off the device?

Tags: ios

I'm getting this message in my logs.

"Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new log

I assume this refers to the device as I have deleted the crashreports in XCode.

How can I delete iOS crash reporter logs off  the device?

Comment: This is not a programming question. This question should be deleted from SO.

Comment: @HangarRash What is your definition of programming? Would questions about running a compiler be removed? What about setting up an IDE? I think you are being a little bit dogmatic. 57k views and 40 upvotes indicate that people find this useful, which in my opinion is the whole point of SO.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Disconnect your device and close Xcode.

On your dev machine you should look in:

```
/Users/%username%/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/%devicename%
```

Move all reports to the Trash and then sync your device with iTunes. That should remove the logs from the device.

Comment: I'm also getting this error after moving to GM Xcode 5. There are no logs saved on the machine at this location

Comment: I just searched for "CrashReporter" on my OS X 10.9 (Xcode 5 GM-only system): and found it at /Users/%username/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice. @cynistersix please ensure that you've recently synced a device that contains crash logs.

Comment: Actually, just deleted that folder and re-synced one of my devices. The crash logs still end up in that folder.

Comment: Didn't help for me. So I deleted all logs in the Organizer beginning from the top.

Comment: Thanks! it work. How smart Apple guy :(, it still here on iOS 8.1.3 and Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: This help me,thank you! Remember to sync using iTunes

Answer (score 12):

The directory `/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter` is the one in your iOS device, instead of your Mac OS X/Windows computer. The directory `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice` mentioned by another answer, could be simply removed by using Xcode Devices (shortcut in Xcode: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>)

So if your want to remove iOS device crashlogs, you need to get into that dir. If you jailbreaked your iOS device, you could ssh to your iOS device with default password `alpine` (if you did not change it)

```
ssh root@x.x.x.x
```

`x.x.x.x` is the IP address of your iOS device.

after you sshed to your iOS device, Now you could remove all files/directories in it to free some space:

```
cd /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
rm -rf *
```

Answer (score 11):

Syncing your device through iTunes will remove the logs from your device.

Comment: Out of all of the answers here (except maybe Sean's for Jailbroken devices) this one is the only that works for iOS 9.

Answer (score 8):

To delete crash logs on iOS device.

1. In Xcode, Devices window, with device selected, click View Device Logs button.
2. A modal window pops up listing all logs in left pane, and selected log contents in right pane.
3. Click top log item in left pane.
4. Scroll to bottom of log list.
5. Shift-Click on log item at bottom of list. All log items will be selected.
6. Press Delete key.
7. Confirmation dialog box appears.
8. Confirm deletion in dialog box.
9. Done!

Comment: Did not fix this issue at all. Device is still apparently full of logs, despite deleting them all via this method.

Comment: There is no logs in this pane, yet saying reached limit. stupid device